# Titanium Appcelerator through a corporate proxy

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator

So I was wondering if anyone has had any success getting Titanium's Appcelerator working behind a corporate proxy.  I can't seem to find any information about how to enter proxy information in the SDK.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is being behind the proxy preventing you from doing? My corporate proxy blocks project tracking and such, but it doesn't prevent me from developing and testing.

Comment: It's preventing me from even logging in.  It works if I connect through an external network, but then I can't develop because the API's I need to implement need to be implemented on the network...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find the documentation for setting the Titanium Developer proxy settings but you might want to try Titanium Studio.

You can download it at http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/

Here is an article on how to configure it for proxy access.
http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+Aptana+Studio+from+behind+a+web+proxy

Comment: That did the trick.  The first time I logged in, I had to do it off the network, but once I set up the proxy settings, we were good to go.  :)  Thanks for the help.

Comment: The wiki page has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following lines to the TitaniumStudio.ini, setting the JVM proxy:

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.intranet
-Dhttps.proxyPort=1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Ben Bahrenburg your link doesn't work anymore...

I have been able to set it up properly by editing "Network Connections" preferences and the "TitaniumStudio.ini" located at the root of the application.

Here is what I specified in "Window / Preferences / Network Connections" :

[image]

Here is what I added within the TitaniumStudio.ini file (Mine is located in "C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Titanium Studio\TitaniumStudio.ini")

Copy / paste stuff between "-vmargs" and "-Xms40m" lines

```
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.business.com
-Dhttp.proxyPort=80
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0
-Xms40m
```

Unfortunatly, the Dashboard Browser still doesn't work. It shows "This program canoot display webpage". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to update this thread with new info. In the latest Titanium Studio (3.x), there is now a proxy setup button on the login screen. Select protocol, add URL and port(if other than default), check Require Authentication box, and enter proxy login credentials.

Worked for me.